# How do I upgrade my west of loathing stats

Tags: west-of-loathing

how do you up your stats in west of loathing? As in what button do I use for it if tried the arrows and stuff but I cant find it out

Answer (score 3):

By default, your character will be upgraded automatically as soon as you accumulated enough XP for the next upgrade the algorithm considers appropriate.  If you prefer to manage your character progression yourself, you can switch that off by unchecking "Automatically Spend XP" in the options menu.

You can increase your stats in your character menu (<kbd>C</kbd>) by clicking on the crosses (red circles). Note that in order to do that, you need enough unspent XP points (green circle). You gain XP mostly by winning battles and completing quests, but there are also various other activities in the game which give you small amounts of XP.

[image: Character Menu]

Comment: @craftycrafter64 When this answer answered your question, please accept it by clicking the checkmark-icon next to it.